# How to remove variable from last iteration of while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm not an expert at python and I've got the following `while` loop. It is padding the iterations into buffer. However, this results in some unwanted padding in the last iteration of the `while loop`. Is there any way I can remove this?

```
    # Send data packets.
bytes_sent = 0
while (bytes_sent < len(padded_buf)):
  bytes_to_send = len(padded_buf) - bytes_sent
  assert bytes_to_send % 4 == 0
  bytes_this_block = min(_MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, bytes_to_send)
  s.send(padded_buf[bytes_sent:(bytes_sent + bytes_this_block)])
  bytes_sent += bytes_this_block

# Clean up and return.
s.close()
return bytes_sent
```

Cheers for any helps.

Comment: I don't see any buffer that things are being padded into. You've got a `padded_buf`, but you don't mutate that at all. The only thing you update anywhere is `bytes_sent`. Do you want to not count some of the bytes in `bytes_sent` because they're padding? If so… what's the rule for which ones don't count?

Comment: This code is sending padded_buf, _MAX_BLOCK_SIZE bytes at a time. Its not padding anything. From the variable name, I'd guess you did the padding elsewhere and that is where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to remove… but whatever it is, you can do it easily.

If you really want to remove it after the fact, you can. All of the variables you define inside the `while` loop are still available after its done, with their value from the last iteration. So you can just do something like this:

```
padded_buf = padded_buf[:-bytes_this_block]
```

But really, it would be better to not add it in the first place. Just put an `if` statement in the middle of the while and `break` if you've reached the end.